# Need some mouse click advice on Python inactive windows

Tags: python

I implemented using Python to take screenshots using openCv when certain windows are screen covered and inactive, and I even got coordinate values by searching images..

And what I want to try is to send a message to the window handler through sendMessage or postMessage in that coordinate and click on that coordinate. Of course, even when the screen is blocked and inactive..

Does not move to the specified coordinates in a specific window..Click occurs only when the mouse cursor enters the window area.  I also tried wndProc, and the mouse cursor moves for pyautoit or pyautogui.

I want to move the mouse cursor where I want to, and click on the coordinates that I specify independently of the window handler..Please give me some advice..

I implemented using Python to take screenshots using openCv when certain windows are screen covered and inactive, and I even got coordinate values by searching images..
And what I want to try is to send a message to the window handler through sendMessage or postMessage in that coordinate and click on that coordinate. Of course, even when the screen is blocked and inactive..
Does not move to the specified coordinates in a specific window..Click occurs only when the mouse cursor enters the window area.  I also tried wndProc, and the mouse cursor moves for pyautoit or pyautogui.
I want to move the mouse cursor where I want to, and click on the coordinates that I specify independently of the window handler..Please give me some advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.